# Override template phtml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, xml, phtml

**First** 
I have created a module and place it in a file I want to override

> \app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

The original location is

> vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

**Second** 
I added `backend_widget_grid.xml` located in

> \app\code\BodyMod\OrdersPopupButton\view\adminhtml\layout\backend_widget_grid.xml

And the content of the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="widget.extended">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::widget/grid/extended.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I don't see my edits so can somebody tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: Is backend_widget_grid.xml a custom layout?

Answer (score 1):

Override `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended` like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid;

class Extended extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::widget/grid/extended.phtml';
}
```

and in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Extended" />
</config>
```

Comment: This looks like a way to override php not phtml. Is the first file you meantion named Extended.php in Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\ and should di.xml be in etc/adminhtml/ ?

Comment: yes, this is the way. You cannot override the template of this block inside a layout file because this block is not called directly in any layout .

Comment: Yes, i found the same way elsewhere so you are right, but I still can't see my edits

Comment: Unless it's unavoidable please do not declare or override templates this way. It makes it very difficult for front-end developers to work with it, although at times the core hard codes templates this way (like this) :(

Comment: yes, i agree with you, @BenCrook. Probably, the best way to do this override is to override the template directly inside your custom admin theme folder, under `Magento_Backend`

Comment: @GeorgeM where should I put edited version of the extend.phtml file?

Comment: @BenCrook can you please tell me what is the recommendable way

Comment: The best way is to define the template in layout XML, example - `<block class="enter\your\class\here" name="name.here" template="Vendor_Module::your-template.phtml" />`. Doing it this way makes it much easier for front-end developers to work with your block. I mean this in general though, it may not be possible for this use case.

Comment: @KonstantinPatroev The correct location is `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid/extended.phtml`